# Can I Add Passbook App in iOS6 Simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, passbook

I could create Sample.pkpass.

Naturally, I created a Pass Type ID, sample.cer, sample.p12 from iOS Provisioning Portal.

Also I created logo.png, logo@2x.png, pass.json, manifest.json.
Then I created S/MIME signatured, zip compressed.
Then, I tried sample.pkpass on iOS6 Simulator to Safari.

```
http://localhost/sample/sample.pkpass
```

I was able to see my Boarding Pass.
Then, I pushed the "Add" Button in the top right part of the screen.
Then, my Boarding Pass has disappeared from the screen.

So, I started Passbook App, but I could not see my Boarding Pass.

Is it because the application is running in Simulator?

Comment: I believe it is because passbook is supposed to work over `https`. It might even work on iOS Simulator, but it fails on real device that is not enabled for development. Once you enable your device for development on the apple website and thru xcode, http toggle appears in the `Settings` tab, under `Developer`, `Allow HTTP Services`.